# Fetch not defined even though i have it installed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have fetch installed in using npm. But I get it as undefined. Where is the issue here?
when I try from command line, I get a error.

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mott\Documents\Node.Js.Code\test2.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

```js
fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5d99501d3d6e417eb7570de2")
.then(function(resp){
    return resp.json();
 

})
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
);
```

Comment: Fetch is a client-side api. Installing it via npm just installs a polyfill for older browsers, it doesn't run in node.js which already has plenty of HTTP options anyway.

Comment: Are you referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch?

Comment: Actually, it looks like your error is not with this code, but when  you're trying to load the fetch module and then error is either because you don't have the fetch module installed properly or the import/require statement that loads it (which you don't show us) is incorrect.

Comment: jfriend00 is right. i assumed that fetch is loaded module is loaded by default. This went way when i added  the following. is there qny other method to load it automatically?
const fetch = require('node-fetch');